# Office 365 Custom List View

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, ms-office

I previously created a website using ASP.NET that stores contact information and can produce (using an ASP.NET repeater and SQL Datasource) name badges, suitable for printing.

We are migrating this over to Office 365 and using the Sharepoint functionality within that.

I want the list output to look something like this:

[image: badges]

The fields are all in a list view and the tick boxes are Yes/No fields, is this possible using XLV/XML/XSLT? I have tried using Sharepoint Designer to modify a list view but have had little success. Any advice/code much appreciated.

Comment: After further reading I have established that a XSLT List View Web Part is the way to go, but am still lacking knowledge of implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone else, after much research, I found this fantastic blog post offering some sample code and an example, and with it I was able to achieve what I wanted.

http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-customizing.html